# How can I get user input on Windows without echo in a Python script?

Tags: python, windows

I'm using python 2.7.9 on Windows 7. I need to obtain a password from a user in order to connect to a resource. It seems that `userpass = getpass.getpass("Password :")` is the de facto standard for this in Python, however in Windows 7, the inputted text is just happily echoed to the output screen.

How can I mask the user input in the console or whatever when running my Python script?
Thank you

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/2625645

Comment: Do you get the message: "Warning: Problem with getpass. Passwords may be echoed."???

Comment: There is an activestate recipe [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579148-add-password-masking-ability-to-getpassgetpass/).

Comment: There is no general way to do this for "whatever" console, terminal, or input window is being used. On Windows, `getpass.getpass` can read without echo from the Windows console, but its test for switching to the fallback is horrible: i.e. `sys.stdin is not sys.__stdin__`. Are you trying to read from the console?

Comment: @Gribouillis - thanks, I was hopeful but seems that the recipe has some error in it as it still echoes the typed characters... still debugging it...

Comment: @eryksun - yes. I'm protoyping a mysql DB connection in a DOS window so ..  STDIN equivalent is not equivalent I take it.

Comment: You mean a console window. Python hasn't supported DOS for many years. Anyway, are you replacing `sys.stdin`? If so, that explains why it's using the fallback that echoes user input.

Comment: Ok, I was running from within IDLE, hitting [F5].  I launched it today in a DOS/CMD window and it properly masks the password.  Thanks for all the help.